# Amplify GraphQL query returns 'AccessDeniedException' error while trying to retrieve data from an AWS database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify, credentials, amplifyjs

I have an issue with creadential. I create project and graphQL database.

```
type FAQ @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  answer: String!
  question: String!
}
```

After I tried to get all the FAQs.

```
import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import { listFAQS } from '../../../graphql/queries';
const faqs = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listFAQS));
```

But got the error
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE3ZE.png)]
I am a newbee in AWS development. Please help me.

I tried to get data from AWS Database

Comment: I believe you need to create an IAM role for unauthenticated access.